# Ext JS 5.1- How a date field can be masked like 00/00/0000?

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, masking, extjs5

I am working with Ext JS 5.1 which is very new. So I can't able to find masking property. On page load I want a date field to be appearing as '00/00/0000'. With the help of reMask property I am able to restrict users to put only numbers there. But I want while entering the date, the field should be appeared like 02/24/2015. The User must not put '/' explicitly. It should be there always. while erasing the date, the '/' shouldn't be erased. Only numbers must be erased then and it will appear like '--/--/----'.

Please provide me some guidance so I can proceed with my work. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This project might give you a starting point:

https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.form.field.Phone

The class itself accepts a tpl which you could likely customise for your needs:

https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.form.field.Phone/blob/master/packages/Ux.form.field.Phone/src/form/field/Phone.js

Comment: It is not what I am looking for. Though it is helpful in some way. Thanks buddy.